# derived function is invoked instead of base c++

Tags: c++

Why does below code invoke base class' method in the second call?

Base class:

```
class Number{

      public:
         Number(){}     

        virtual print(){cout<<"Number"<<endl;}
        virtual bool isEqual (Number* number){ cout<<"Base class"<<endl;}
};
```

Derived class :

```
class Int: public Number{
   int member;
     public:
        Int(int number){ member =number; }

       int get Number(){ return member; }
       print(){ cout<<"member"<<endl;}
       bool isEqual(Int* number){ return member == number->getNumber(); }
};
```

Main function:

```
int main(){
Int i1(3);
Int i2(4);

Number* nPtr = &i1;

nPter->print();  ///  prints 3
nPter->isEqual(&i2); /// "Base class"

...
```

by the way:

```
i1.isEqual(&i2); /// prints 0 -- works fine
```

Comment: Try adding `override` to those functions. You'd be surprised. Also, `print` is missing a return type. It's a bit too pseudo for pseudo code.

Comment: isEqual has different signatures in base and derived class. You have overloaded the function. When you call with base class pointer it calls Number::isEqual and when you call with Int pointer/ref. it call Int::isEqual.

Answer (score 1):

`bool(Int*)` is not the same type as `bool(Number*)`, hence your function `Int::isEqual` does *not* override `Number::isEqual` -- rather, it's a completely separate function.

Just think about it for a minute; the attempted override makes no sense: Your derived class expects a constrained argument, but the base function's parameter is less constrained! If what you wanted were allowed,  `nPtr->isEqual` could be called with *any* `Number` pointer, which the derived class does not support!

---

<sub>The correct question would be for *covariant* return types but *contravariant* parameters. However, C++ does not allow contravariant parameter overriders.</sub>

Comment: So the compile overrides functions according to name and return type.

Comment: @AbdKhatib: No. According to name and *type*. (Notably, your two functions do have the same *return* type. They don't, however, have the same *type*.)

Comment: And function with different arguments are considered different functions?

Comment: @AbdKhatib - Yes. C++ allows you to overload all sorts of functions. Note it's not the same as *override* virtual members.